# RegEx to restrict the number of UTF-16 code units for an XSD file

Tags: regex, unicode, xsd

I'm working on an XSD file for XML files that need to be sent to a legacy system. This legacy system has field size restrictions specified in # of UTF-16 code units.

For example, the field `description` may not contain more than 35 UTF-16 code units.

**I'm now trying to come up with a regular expression that I can put into the XSD so that it restricts the respective field value to contain at most 35 UTF-16 codes units.**

My first attempt was this:

```
    <xs:element name="description">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>A description for the document</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>A sequence of up to 35 UTF-16 code units</xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:pattern value="^(|([\x{0}-\x{FFFF}][\x{0}-\x{FFFF}]|[\x{10000}-\x{10FFFF}]){0,17}[\x{0}-\x{FFFF}]?|[\x{0}-\x{FFFF}]?([\x{0}-\x{FFFF}][\x{0}-\x{FFFF}]|[\x{10000}-\x{10FFFF}]){0,17})$"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
```

Some background behind this regular expression:

- A BMP (basic multilingual plane) character (`[\x{0}-\x{FFFF}]`) is represented as a single UTF-16 code unit.
- An astral plane character (`[\x{10000}-\x{10FFFF}]`) is represented as two UTF-16 code units (as a surrogate pair).

My (failed) idea was to implement this restriction:

- There are at most 17 groups that are either a) a pair of BMP characters, or b) a single astral plane character.
- These at most 17 groups may either be preceded or followed by a single BMP character.

But obviously, this fails for strings like `aaa` where there is a single BMP character in between two astral plane characters.

Is there maybe another way to implement a restriction for the number of UTF-16 code units in an XSD file?

Comment: First of all, remove `^` and `$`, XSD patterns are anchored by default.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I put those in only for the convenience of copy/pasting the RegEx into https://regex101.com/ or the like. In the final version the anchors will be removed.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to solve this issue with a regex that does not support lookarounds. You would need to spell out all the possible variations, and that is unwieldly.